# sql : which dates contain time between 12:00 and 22:00

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

i have `myTable` with column `RecTime AS DATETIME`

```
RecTime
-----------------------
2013-05-22 15:32:37.530
2013-05-22 22:11:16.103
2013-05-22 16:24:06.883
2013-05-22 16:38:30.717
2013-05-22 23:54:41.777
2013-05-23 22:01:00.000
2013-05-23 09:59:59.997
```

i need an SQL statement that tell me which dates contain time between 12:00 and 22:00

expected result is :-

```
RecTime                 | foo
------------------------|-----
2013-05-22 15:32:37.530 |   1
2013-05-22 22:11:16.103 |   0
2013-05-22 16:24:06.883 |   1
2013-05-22 16:38:30.717 |   1
2013-05-22 23:54:41.777 |   0
2013-05-23 22:01:00.000 |   0
2013-05-23 09:59:59.997 |   0
```

for now i use the following :-

```
SELECT 
    [RecTime]
    , CASE WHEN [RecTime] >= CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, [RecTime])) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, [RecTime])) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(DAY, [RecTime])) + ' 12:00')
            AND [RecTime] <= CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, [RecTime])) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, [RecTime])) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(DAY, [RecTime])) + ' 22:00')
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END  
FROM dbo.myTable
```

and i know this is not the best solution / performance.

help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more approach

```
SELECT RecTime, 
       CASE WHEN CAST(RecTime AS TIME) 
                 BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '22:00:00' 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END foo
  FROM Table1
```

Output:

```
|                    RECTIME | FOO |
|----------------------------|-----|
| May, 22 2013 15:32:37+0000 |   1 |
| May, 22 2013 22:11:16+0000 |   0 |
| May, 22 2013 16:24:06+0000 |   1 |
| May, 22 2013 16:38:30+0000 |   1 |
| May, 22 2013 23:54:41+0000 |   0 |
| May, 23 2013 22:01:00+0000 |   0 |
| May, 23 2013 09:59:59+0000 |   0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a503/6)** demo

Comment: Doh, for some reason I thought you'd need a sub select

Answer (score 3):

You've found [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) and yet the obvious didn't spring to mind:

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,[RecTime]) >= 12
     AND DATEPART(hour,[RecTime]) < 22
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
```

As a side note, when working with a continuum like time, it's almost always more sensible to define semi-open intervals (where you use `>=` on the start and `<` on the finish), otherwise you end up with oddities such as 22:00:00.000 exactly being included in your period, and 22:00:00.003 being excluded. That's rarely correct. I've adjusted my query to match this pattern.

---

> i know this is not the best solution / performance.

Performance is always going to be poor for this query because we'll never be able to leverage an index. If this is a frequent form of query (querying on just the Hour component), you might consider adding a computed column which you can then index.

---

To include 22:00:00.000 exactly, I'd handle that as a separate, specialised case:

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,[RecTime]) >= 12
     AND DATEPART(hour,[RecTime]) < 22
    THEN 1
     WHEN DATEPART(hour,RecTime) = 22 AND DATEPART(minute,RecTime) = 0 and DATEPART(second,RecTime) = 0 and DATEPART(millisecond,RecTime) = 0
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
```

Comment: i fully understand your worry about the "wrong" logic, but the circumstance where i use the condition is required `<=` and not '<'

Comment: @armen - I'd handle that as a separate `WHEN` clause. I've added an example at the bottom.

Comment: I like this approach. The only thing I'm unsure about, is the performance of `DATEPART()` vs `CAST()` suggested by @peterm. I will heavily test those methods and if `DATEPART()` wins, than this is going to become my chosen answer!

Comment: looks like `DATEPART()` method uses more CPU power then `CAST() AS TIME` ( the table contains 120.000.000 rows, and the difference in execution time is 20 min ). for now will stick with @peterm 's method !

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
[RecTime],
(Select CASE 
     WHEN DATEPART(hour,[RecTime])  between 12 AND 22 Then 1 
else 0
END
From dbo.myTable ) as foo
 From dbo.myTable
```

Comment: this approach has a little problem when hour is 22 and minute, second and millisecond is greater than 0. as you see in my example second line from the end must return 0 because it's greater than 22:00:00.000

Comment: I wouldn't expect that. Thanks for letting me know.